# Cannot check for specific parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if an element has a parent/grandparent with a certain class. My code does not work correctly:

[**js fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YK7XH/3/)

JavaScript:

```
$("body").on("click", function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).parents(".granny")) alert("you have a granny");
});
```

Comment: use .granny instead granny

Comment: It still does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check null objects in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477667/how-to-check-null-objects-in-jquery).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if( $(e.target).parents(".granny") )` will always be true since you are checking the jQuery object, which is a truthy value.

Check the length property instead :

```
if( $(e.target).parents(".granny").length )
```

When searching for a parent, [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) may be interesting since it is way faster. It doesn't loop through all parents, it stop once it find a match.

While `parents` doesn't stop until it reach the root of the document, `.parents()` doesn't include the target itself. That mean that is you click on `.granny` directly (it become the `e.target`) while using `closest`, the alert will pop while `parents` will not.

Knowing that, you are the only juge on what method you really need.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `closest()` it stops once there is a match .

```
$("body").on("click", function(e){
    if( $(e.target).closest(".granny").length ){
        alert("you have a granny");
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YK7XH/11/)

Comment: As stated by Frédéric Hamidi in a comment that he deleted on my answer, `.closest` include the element itself while `.parents` doesn't. Technically, if you click on the granny, she doesn't have a granny (she is the granny). OP may not want that.