# How to check with jquery if this conent is null

Tags: jquery

I have the following code , how can I check if this content is null with jquery ? Could anyone help to me ?

```
 .append("<div class='form-group'><textarea rows='5' class='input-text full-width description' >"+data.pi.description+"</textarea></div>")
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if `data.pi.description` is null?

Comment: `if (data.pi.description == null)`

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of different ways to check if content is null. Just by the data.pi.description:

```
if (! data.pi.description) ...
```

You could check the div text area with:

```
if (!$(".description").html()) ....
```

or

```
if ( $(".description").length == 0) ...
```

Similar question to [How to check null objects in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477667/how-to-check-null-objects-in-jquery)