# If a field is occupied by another value alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a little Tic Tac Toe game and I want to alert the user when they try to click in a cell which already has a value in it. Here is what I have so far.

```js
    var turn = "O";
     //player 1 = turn  = O
     //player2 = turn  = X
    var cell = $('#cell');

    function go(cellID) {
      //alert(turn);
      var boxId = "#" + cellID;
      if (cell = null) {
        if (turn == 'O') {
          $(boxId).html("O");
          turn = 'X';
        } else {
          if (turn == 'X') {
            $(boxId).html("X");
            turn = 'O';
          }
        }
      } else {
        alert('Pick another box')
      }

      //alert(cellID);
      $('h2:last').html('Turn: ' + turn);
      return turn;
    }
```

```css
.cell {
  height: 20px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameTable">
  <table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td onclick="go('C0')" id="C0" class="cell"></td>
      <td onclick="go('C1')" id="C1" class="cell"></td>
      <td onclick="go('C2')" id="C2" class="cell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="go('C3')" id="C3" class="cell"></td>
      <td onclick="go('C4')" id="C4" class="cell"></td>
      <td onclick="go('C5')" id="C5" class="cell"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="go('C6')" id="C6" class="cell"></td>
      <td onclick="go('C7')" id="C7" class="cell"></td>
      <td onclick="go('C8')" id="C8" class="cell"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your problem? also `if (cell = null)` does not look correct, do you not want `if (cell == null)`?

Comment: Is that the problem cell = null or cell === null ?

Comment: First, its `==` or `===` and not `=` in conditional expression. Second, posting your HTML code would help. Last, read [How to check null objects in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477667/how-to-check-null-objects-in-jquery).

Comment: @bitten you beet me by 6 seconds :D

Comment: @squiroid blessed

Comment: @kieron is that solved your problem or you are looking for something else.

I have created the fiddle for you to play with.

https://jsfiddle.net/9rercohk/

Comment: @keirin you need to add more information about your problem. However, another problem is that `$('#cell');` is looking for something with the ID of "cell" but I think you need the class "cell" : `$('.cell');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. Your check on line 9 is not quite correct. You can see if the value of the element is empty by using `.html()` which returns the content of the element, and if the element is empty it will return an empty string.

`if (cell = null) {` would then become `if ($(boxId).html() === '') {`

[See the updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9rercohk/1/)

Answer (score -1):

As others have stated, your `if (cell = null)` is incorrect and should be `if ($(boxId).html() === '')`.

Another point to make is that you should not be using the `onclick` event inside of your `td` elements. Instead, you should be using jquery's `.on('click')` event.

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcoubfar/3/)