# Removing nulls from html popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup, mapbox

I would like to format the content of my popup so that `null` values are completely removed.  At this point, my popup is filled with the `features.properties` array.  There are 20 elements in `properties`, and depending on the queried feature, many of those values will be `null`.

```
  var feature = features[0];

  // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
  // based on the feature found.

  popup.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
      .setHTML('<div><b>' + feature.properties.city + '</div></b>' + '<div>'
       + feature.properties.course1 + '</div>' + '<div>'+
       feature.properties.course2 + '<div>' + feature.properties.course3 + '</div>')
      .addTo(map);
```

At this point, an example popup with some `null` values looks like this:

[image]

My aim is to eliminate `null` values and not to display them in the popup.

So far I've tried the `JSON.stringify` option instead of listing each element in separate `<div>` element.

```
function replacer(key, value) {
            // Filtering out properties
            if (value === "null" || value === null) {
              return undefined;
            }
            return value;
          }

JSON.stringify(feature.properties, replacer, "\t").replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/,/g, "")
```

This produces the desired result but then formatting is the problem.

[image]

The JSON object does not display well in a popup even when encasing it in `<pre>` tags, which produces:

[image]

I would like to know if there is a solution to format my popup so that it looks like the first image - but excludes null values.  How can one do this is `html` by listing all of the property elements (`course1`, `course2`, `course3`, etc...)  *without*  producing a bunch of empty `<div>` s?

Comment: please look at it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477667/how-to-check-null-objects-in-jquery

Comment: Here's a basic way: https://jsfiddle.net/hjyfhm2y/

Comment: thanks @ChrisG but I just tried that function and it's still producing nulls - I think because the nulls are strings with `"null"`

Comment: In that case: https://jsfiddle.net/hjyfhm2y/1/

Comment: this works!  how would one also exclude, for example, a key called `field_1` or another key ? could you add that update?  If you submit an answer I can mark it as correct.  thanks @ChrisG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using classic Javascript:

```js
var features = {
  properties: {
    city: "Salzburg",
    course1: "DCLead",
    course2: "null",
    course3: null,
    field_1: "Hello"
  }
};

function htmlFromProps(props, exclude) {
  var html = "";
  var i = 0;
  for (p in props) {
    if (props[p] && props[p] != "null" && exclude.indexOf(p) === -1) {
      html += "<div>" + (i === 0 ? "<strong>" : "");
      html += props[p];
      html += (i++ === 0 ? "</strong>" : "") + "</div>\n";
    }
  }
  return html;
}

popup.innerHTML = htmlFromProps(features.properties, ["field_1"]);
```

```css
#popup {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<textarea id="popup"></textarea>
```

Use it by calling `.setHTML(htmlFromProps(features.properties, []))` where the second argument is an array of fields you want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

You could try filtering your properties, see the example below:

```js
var feature = {
  properties: {
    city: 'Salzburg',
    course1: 'test',
    course3: 'test3'
  }
};

var html = Object
  .keys(feature.properties)
  .map(key => feature.properties[key])
  .filter(value => value)
  .map((value, i) => i === 0
      ? `<div><strong>${value}</strong></div>`
      : `<div>${value}</div>`
      )

console.log(html);
```

The crucial part is `.filter(value => value)` where [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) makes sure that only truthy (non-null) values remain in the array.

Comment: If you add `<strong>` to the first `<div>`, this is the perfect answer, assuming the target browsers all support ES2015.

Comment: how would I wrap this in `.setHTML`?

Comment: I updated my answer to include `<strong>`. You can just call `.setHTML(html)`!